# ImageView not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i'm practising doing a instagram clone, however when I run the app the  default images and like label  doesn't show up. where am I going.

this is the code for the feed
     import UIKit

```
 class Feed: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var imageee: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var like: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var user: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var comment: UILabel!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: 
   Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
@IBAction func likeButton(_ sender: Any) {
}
```

This is the feedController view controller.

```
 import UIKit

 class FeedController: UIViewController , 
UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableV: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableV.delegate = self
  //  tablev.datasource = self
    tableV.dataSource = self

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10

}
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
  indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = 


tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cellTable" , for: indexPath) as! Feed
       cell.user.text = "testing12"
        cell.like.text = "0"
       cell.comment.text = "comment"
       cell.imageee.image = UIImage(named: "select.png")
      return cell
  }


   }
```

[image: this is what is showing but i should display the like button and default image view]
where am i going wrong?

Comment: Try to use: `cell.imageee.image = UIImage(named: "select")`

Comment: First, make sure you add your image to the Assets.xcassets file of your project
Next use "select" instead of "select.png".
You can change the background color of UIImageView to easily see it

Comment: Please try @pkc456 code. And also set proper height for each cell so your image dose not hide.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you one example,

For instance I have the follow ViewController .

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }


}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "calendar")
        return cell
    }


}
```

and this is the cell

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {



    @IBOutlet weak var customImage: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


}
```

and this its xib.
[image]

check if you add the image in the Assets.xcassets folder

Comment: but on my case y create custom xib for the cell, and when use xib, you have to register the new cell on the tableview,